# I have three input to enter but it is only allowing me to enter two first one and break on the third

Tags: c, scanf

This program determine the area of the room, which is the product of its length and width.    Whether the room is “too small”, “just right”, or “too large”. If the room is “too small” or “too large”, the difference between the available space and the required space, which should be a positive number.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    // Declare variables and set initial values
    int length, width, n, area, square;
    
    // Print new values
    printf("\nEnter room length:");
    scanf("%d", length);
    printf("\nEnter room width:");
    scanf("%d", width);
    printf("\nEnter number of students:");
    scanf("%d", n);
 
    // assigning area
    area = length * width;
     
    printf("\nArea is %d\n", area); 
    square = area - n * 10; 
    if (area > n*10) {
        printf("Room is too large by %d square feet", square);
    }
    else if (area < n*10) {
        printf("Room is too small by %d square feet", square);
    }
    else {
        printf("Room size is just right");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", length);` ---> `scanf("%d", &length);`, `scanf("%d", width);` ---> `scanf("%d", &width);` and `scanf("%d", n);` ---> `scanf("%d", &n);`. Also, the return type of `main()` should be `int`.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment, `scanf` is expecting to see a pointer. `&n` is saying "get a pointer to the address where `n` is stored."

Comment: If you read about how `scanf`s work, everything afterwards will become easy. That's the most complicated function you'll ever meet.

Comment: Thank H.S! I just changed it but it still not allowing me to enter students number.

Comment: You can't use any input function correctly unless you ***Check The Return*** (this applies with extra vigor to `scanf()` and family...)

Comment: What makes you think that you can't enter the number of students?

Comment: `scanf("%d", length);` is a mistake, but not the **big** mistake.  Save time.  Compile code with a good compiler with all warnings enabled to get good fast feedback why `scanf("%d", length);` is bad.

Comment: "which should be a positive number." --> Roselyne, why use `square` in `printf("Room is too small by %d square feet", square);`?

Comment: thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Declare variables and set initial values
    int length, width, n, area, square;
    
    // Print new values
    printf("\nEnter room length:");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("\nEnter room width:");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("\nEnter number of students:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
 
    // assigning area
    area = length * width;
     
    printf("\nArea is %d\n", area); 
    square = area - n * 10; 
    if (area > n*10) {
        printf("Room is too large by %d square feet", square);
    }
    else if (area < n*10) {
        printf("Room is too small by %d square feet", square);
    }
    else {
        printf("Room size is just right");
    }
    
    return 0;
}`
```

`&` operator required before variable in scanf to store value in that variable

eg `scanf(%d,&b)`

Comment: The `getchar` at the end serves no purpose. If you are trying to keep the program "alive" so the IDE or graphical shell doesn't close the terminal window, it wont help. After the last `scanf`, there is still at least a newline in the input buffer, so `getchar` will return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` after the format specifier `%d` and before the variable as  `&` operator is used to get the address of the variable or take user input, everywhere you use `scanf` except a character array or a string. Use `gets(variable_name)` function to take a character array or string as an input from the user.  For example, if I take your Program, it should be :

```
 printf("\nEnter room length:");
scanf("%d",&length);
printf("\nEnter room width:");
scanf("%d",&width);
printf("\nEnter number of students:");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\n enter name : "); //datatype of Name must be String
gets(name);
```

Comment: Presented as a "rule to remember" as here, this does not provide a helpful learning. Please explain the meaning of `&`. Also consider discussing its absence in case of input of e.g. a word into an array of  `char`.